# Realized variance/volatility as input in Realized GARCH model

Tags: r, variance, garch, volatility

I want to produce one day ahead volatility forecasts with Realized GARCH(1,1) using the `rugarch` package in R. I've defined the realized variance (RV) as the sum of the squared intraday returns. Now, should the input for the realized measure in the model be RV as defined as above, or should it be the realized volatility (square root of RV)? I'm a bit confused since these terms appear to be used interchangeably.

Comment: Does [this worked example](https://www.r-bloggers.com/2014/01/the-realized-garch-model/) by the author of `rugarch` help?

Comment: Thank you Richard!